# Adobe Air: why does this DataProvider create error?

Tags: apache-flex, sqlite, air, flex4, dataprovider

I am currently getting an error at line 148 during runtime:

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at PlantDB/ResultFill()[C:\Users\usern\Adobe Flash Builder 4.6\PlantDB\src\SQLiteCode.as:148]
```

The code at line 148 is:

```
leftList.dataProvider = new ArrayCollection(arr);
```

Before coming to this line 148, the program has checked that Array arr is not null with if (arr != null), so I am 100% sure that arr is not null.

The content of arr is from sqlite:

```
arr = sqls.getResult().data;
```

There are several objects in the database, and I see that I can get the content from the database just fine. In fact, before line 148, I've checked the content inside arr by:

```
var tree:TreeClass_Full = arr[0];
```

In the debugger, I checked the tree object above, and I see that all variables from the sqlite database are transferred to the tree object correctly. In fact, I've checked arr[1], arr[2], etc. as well, and I see that the objects got correct data.

In my opinion, sqlite and all that do not seem to be a problem, but when I add this Array arr to var tree:TreeClass_Full = arr[0];, the error pops out.

I don't get it. Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference? What are the hidden process in dataProvider that causes this error?

My leftList is here:

```
        <s:HGroup width="100%" height="85%" verticalAlign="middle">
            <s:List id = "leftList" width = "45%" height = "95%"
                    dragEnabled="true" dragMoveEnabled="true" dropEnabled="true"
                    itemRenderer="resultRenderer"/>
            <s:List id = "rightList" width = "45%" height = "95%" 
                    dragEnabled="true" dragMoveEnabled="true" dropEnabled="true" 
                    itemRenderer="resultRenderer"/>
        </s:HGroup>
```

and my itemRenderer (resultRenderer) is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:ItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
                autoDrawBackground="true">
    <s:HGroup x="5" y="5" width="350" height="150" horizontalAlign="center" verticalAlign="middle">
         <mx:Image id = "resultImage" width="100" height="100"/> 
         <s:TextArea id="resultTextArea" height="141" editable="false"
                    text = "{data.Common_Name}"/> 
    </s:HGroup>
</s:ItemRenderer>
```

If anybody knows what causes this error during dataProvider, please help.

Comment: No hidden processes. It is `leftList` that doesn't exist. The `ResultFill` method is probably called before `leftList` is created.

Comment: ......I am shocked. O_O I see... Yes, leftList is indeed null. Because my HGroup is in a different viewstack (although the same .mxml file), it does not exist until I choose to view the respective viewstack. Now, would it be possible to have leftList exist without having to switch to the respective viewstack?

Comment: It's possible, but it's not the best approach, especially in a mobile project. You just set the dataProvider whenever the component is created. Easiest way to do this is through binding.

Comment: @Karl To create all of the ViewStack's children before the repsective view is displayed, you must set the creationPolicy. I believe you set it to 'all'.  For various reasons, memory usage being one, you may not want to do this

Comment: By the way, RIAstar, do you want to post your answer? Please allow me to give you some points.

Answer (score 0):

As noted above:

> It is leftList that doesn't exist. The ResultFill method is probably called before leftList is created. leftList is indeed null. Because my HGroup is in a different viewstack (although the same .mxml file), it does not exist until I choose to view the respective viewstack.